# How do I get the group id by supplying the group members ids from a database?

Tags: mysql

So, I have a table named kittens, and the schema looks a bit like this.

```
kittens:
id | group | kitten_id
1  | 2     | 0001
2  | 2     | 0002
3  | 2     | 0003
4  | 3     | 0001
5  | 3     | 0002
6  | 3     | 0004
7  | 2     | 0005
8  | 4     | 0005
9  | 4     | 0006
```

What I am trying to do is extract the id of the group by supplying the members. For example, if I want to get the group of the following users (0001, 0002, 0004) I should be able to get group number 3. Now, if (0001, 0002) are entered no group should return, since those two are not in an individual group by themselves. I am completely lost. I have tried selecting using Like: like this.

```
SELECT group FROM kittens where kitten_id IN (0001, 0002, 0004)
```

This is where I am stuck at since this will return every group those members are in.

Comment: What’s the expected output?

Comment: If I send the database the following ids: (0005, 0006) I should be able to get group 4.

Comment: Have you taken a look at what DISTINCT does for you?

Comment: for some reason, that doesn't work for me, but I will keep looking for solutions. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can do something like this:

```
SELECT kitten_group, COUNT(DISTINCT kitten_id) AS counts FROM kittens 
 WHERE kitten_id IN (0001, 0002, 0004)
 GROUP BY kitten_group
HAVING counts = 3
```

Add `COUNT(DISTINCT kitten_id)` to count how many unique `kitten_id` appeared in a group and add `GROUP BY kitten_group`. Then use the count result matching with the lookup value int `HAVING`.

Note that `GROUP` is MySQL reserve keyword so if you want to use it as column name, you have to wrap it in backticks on your query. In this example I changed the column name to `kitten_group`. Also note that `GROUPS` is a reserved keyword added in MySQL 8.0.2. [Here's a documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G).

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=037dfe2503c7c4b1b604e3d3e60d8ec5)

Comment: thank you for taking the time and helping me. This works, but you can encounter a problem when you run a query selecting two members that are found in different groups. Take a look at this fiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=63a09e4628871243091ef8c3bbeb8475

Comment: That's another issue. I suggest you update your question two clarify if there are more than 1 group matches the condition, which group should be returned.